# Does any one know PL/SQL queries I need to do this and I added my code

Tags: oracle, plsql

Question: Write an anonymous PL/SQL program to print our reviews decisions and comments for round 1 reviews of paper titled 'comparing big data systems' in the same program, please also print out any automatic suggestion for this paper. The suggestions should be 'reject' if at least two reviewers' decisions are rejected. the suggestion should be 'accept' if all reviewers' decisions are accepted. all other cases the suggestion is ' to be decided by editor'

My code:

```
begin
    select count(distinct rid) as reviewers_not_submitted_review
    from paper_review 
    where receive_date is null 
    and pid= (select pid from paper where title='Comparing big data systems')
end;
```

I am suppose to use explicit cursors to print out the review decision and comments, and a few implicit cursors to compute number of round1 review for that paper, number of accept and number of reject decisions, and use if then else to come up with suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please format your code, using the {} icon or highlight id and use Ctrl+K, or place it between lines containing only ```. Further get into the habit of structuring it and not just as 1 big string.  Also review the help section [ask]. In this caseyou need to post table definitions (ddl) and sample data, as formatted test - **no images** (even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)) , and the  expected results for that data

Comment: By the way, PL/SQL is a programming language used for writing procedures, functions, triggers, type methods etc. It doesn't do queries - that would be the job of SQL.